# read docx file error

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

```
import docx2txt

my_text=docx2txt.process("file1.docx")
print(my_text)
```

when I want to read the docx file from this code it shows the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1093, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: docx files are really XML and some metadata in a zip file. In order to parse, it needs to unzip it first. zip is asserting it is unable unzip the file (it's either not a real docx file or it has been corrupted to the point that its magic number does not indicate a zip compressed file). Does `file1.docx` actually open in unzip/winzip/7zip and Office (where it doesn't say it's in office 97 compatiblity mode)?

Comment: @cowbert Now i check it was corrupt that's why it's not working. Can you tell me how to read doc file

Comment: Jay, u can try python-docx module to read word documents by import docx.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue as some of my doc files were open. Duplicates used by the OS caused the issue. The moment I closed the working version of these docs. The code worked fine

Answer (score 3):

As @cowbert mentioned in the comment section, your file likely has been corrupted or it's in a zip format. Your provided code is correct. You can also use [textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which supports `.docx` files:

```
import textract
text = textract.process("path/to/file.extension")
```

This package is built on top of several python packages and other source libraries. Once you install it, [several packages](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/blob/master/requirements/python) (including docx2txt) are all installed by default with this package.

Comment: is textract is working in pyhthon3?

Comment: Yes it should, just make sure to install `pip` or `easy_install` to install textract